# Radeon hybrid ATI Radeon card and fglrx problem - update OpenGL to 4.3

Tags: graphics, lenovo, radeon, fglrx, opengl

I have Lenovo G500H with Radeon HD8570M (and Intel) graphics card and my goal was to get OpenGL 4.+ version to be able to use double precision variables in shading language. Long story short, after reinstalling Ubuntu... 5 times? Now I am literally too scared to install any of fglrx driver, or [AMD official update](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Latest-LINUX-Beta-Driver.aspx)

Why? Because any time I do this, I get low graphics mode. When I use `sudo apt-get install` I can just remove these drivers and everything is back to normal. When I tried to uninstall the official AMD driver, best I got (after blank screen and graphics artifacts during starting OS) was broken gnome screen.

I also run Windows 7 (which I use for gaming), here I have newest Catalyst and when I play games the system uses the Radeon card, no problem here. So I don't think my Radeon card is broken.

Ehm - any ideas how I can update OpenGL WITHOUT having to reinstall Ubuntu again? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the way. After installing any fglrx driver I just need simply to do:

```
sudo Xorg :1 -configure
sudo cp xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```